# How to repair PDF with wrong orientation with Itext

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

We have some documents which looks like a normal A4 0 degree rotation document, but they are not. My watermark is not showing correctly on them because of that.

I used:

> int rotate = page.GetRotation();

to check the rotation and in some places it shows 270 and in some 90. Maybe someone has thoughts how to repair that document using Itext? I tried:

```
if (rotate == 270) {
    page.SetRotation(0);}
```

It turns the pages, but then it looks visually like landscape, but actually is portrait.
The example of PDF is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WSvOw0v8ehHD8GJRLfD31Pk0eDiV-oKM/view).

Comment: Your example PDF pages have a landscape mediabox but by means of page rotation are displayed as portrait pages. There is nothing broken or invalid about this. Thus, there is nothing to repair in those documents. Apparently, therefore, the code applying your watermark is broken or simply not designed to be applied to such PDFs.

Comment: Thanks. I have been dealing with it several hours. And still cant understand what I need to change in my function then. I have been trying to change mediabox size, page width and height. And still my watermarks are applied in landscape mode instead of portrait.

Comment: I now managed to solve that :) I needed to select angle and width by hand. It toked a while, but now it is done. Thanks.